# How to Break json data in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this JSON array and i want to break first and second key:

```
[{"first":[{"id":"9","navn":"Test tilvalg 6"}],"second":305.55555555556}]
```

In jquery i want load first key data in select box and wirte second key data i span.

Comment: share code of what you have already tried, so people can guide where you are wrong.

Comment: Shivam Thank you for paying attention on my code but sorry you are late for answering i already got my answer from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

try this way, see below sample code.

```
var json = [{"first":[{"id":"9","navn":"Test tilvalg 6"}],"second":[{"total":305.55555555556}]}];

//first key 
 console.log(json[0].first)

//second key 
 console.log(json[0].second)
```

Comment: How to break {"pris":"420"} if i want to get value of pris

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var json = '[{"first":[{"id":"9","navn":"Test tilvalg 6"}],"second":[{"total":305.55555555556}]}]';

$.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
    // DO your work here
});
```

Comment: How to break {"pris":"420"} if i want to get value of pris